# Drawing parallel rectangles in SwiftUI to create a Calendar Icon

Tags: ios, xcode, swiftui

I'm trying to create a cardView that has a Date on it. Right now, I have the below look, with today's Date within a Square.

I would like to add 2 parallel lines (shown as RED coloured Lines in below pic) such that it looks like a Calendar Icon. Is it possible to do it using `Rectangle()` instead of using `path()`

Q: How do I draw the 2 lines thru the top, centre of the Square?

I've tried permutations of this

```
Rectangle().frame(width: 3, height: 5, alignment: .top).opacity(0.9)
```

but obviously, it didn't work as the line ended up in the middle of the Date.

```
      VStack {
          Text(FormatDisplay.yyyymmdd_day0(inputDate: workout.date))
            .padding(2)
            .background(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 2).stroke(Color(UIColor.label).opacity(0.8), lineWidth: 2))
            .font(.footnote)
            .minimumScaleFactor(0.5)

        if workout.icuId != "" {
          Image("intervalsLogo")
            .resizable()
            .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
            .frame(width: 20, height: 20, alignment: .top)
            .clipShape(Circle())
        }
        
        if workout.priorityCompliance > 0 {
          RingView(compliancePct: workout.priorityCompliance, lineWidth: 2, primaryColor: Color.orange, secondaryColor: Color.orange, size: .tiny)
            .frame(width: 20, height: 20)
            .font(.caption)
          
        }
        Spacer()
      }
    }
```

[image]

This is what the end result I'm looking for. (the horizontal line above the number is an added bonus if possible)

[image]

Comment: Please show the exact code you have tried. It is probably something pretty simple to fix, but the code you have shown would not create what you have shown in the image, it would just create a rectangle.

Comment: @Yrb I could've sworn I pasted the code in it. Anyways, I have pasted it now but lo and behold, I figured out how to do it and like you said, it's pretty simple. Tx

Answer (score 1):

I have bit modified your code. get This if useful.

```
 RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 3)
            .stroke(Color(UIColor.label).opacity(0.8), lineWidth: 3)
            .frame(width: 35, height: 35, alignment: .center)
            .overlay(
                
                VStack(spacing: 2.5) {
                    
                    HStack(spacing: 8) {
                        ForEach(0..<3) { _ in
                            RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 3)
                                .stroke(Color.black.opacity(0.8), lineWidth: 1.5)
                                .frame(width: 1, height: 7, alignment: .top)
                        }
                    }
                    .offset(y: -3.5)
                    
                    RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 3)
                        .stroke(Color.black.opacity(0.8), lineWidth: 1.5)
                        .frame(height: 1)
                        .padding(.horizontal, 5)
                    
                    Text(date)
                        .font(.system(size: 15))
                        .fontWeight(.bold)
                }
                
                ,alignment: .top
            )
```

[preview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TFd50.png)

Comment: V nice... really looks like the icon...

Answer (score 0):

So yeah.. couple hours after I posted this.. figured out the solution.
Key was using the `.offset(x: y:)` modifier

```
      VStack {
        ZStack {
          Text(FormatDisplay.yyyymmdd_day0(inputDate: workout.date))
            .offset(y: 1)
          
          RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 2)
            .stroke(Color(UIColor.label).opacity(0.8), lineWidth: 2)
            .frame(width: 20, height: 20, alignment: .center)
            .offset(y: 0)
          
          RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 2)
            .stroke(Color.black.opacity(0.8), lineWidth: 2)
            .frame(width: 1, height: 6, alignment: .top)
            .offset(x: 4, y: -10)
          
          RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 2)
            .stroke(Color.black.opacity(0.8), lineWidth: 2)
            .frame(width: 1, height: 6, alignment: .top)
            .offset(x: -4, y: -10)
          
        }
```

[image]